# Developing applications for IE 8

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools

Anyone know of any good references for building applications for IE 8?  I found this http://www.apress.com/book/view/1430228539 (but not yet released)

for example:  I would like to build a simple toolbar app that records visited websites.  That possible?

Or are they other suggestions on how to build this type of application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753587%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

MSDN seems like the ideal source.